# rbenv missing GNU coreutils

Tags: ruby, rbenv

[image]

Hi guys ive been wandering about fews hours on google searching if theres any other issue like this with solution.

I did the readme installation of [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#installation) and restart my terminal to see if it works.

Buts im still failing in this part in my windows 7 machine x86.

note: this is fix..

Comment: You probably need Cygwin, not Msysgit.

Comment: @CodeGnome done same through in cygwin! but still same..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it out that rbenv wouldnt work in windows.

instead theres another tool called [PIK](https://github.com/vertiginous/pik) use as alternative for RVM